# NodeJS sequelize model issues

Tags: node.js, orm, model, sequelize.js, migration

Since yet I have always worked in C# with ORM's like Entity Framework, but now I want to start with NodeJS, since I need it for school.

In NodeJS I started using Sequelize since it seems to be the most famous ORM for NodeJS, but I have quite a few problems with it:

1. Why do I have to write, when chaning or expanding a model, the changes on my own in a migration. Is there a way to let a package automated write my migrations depending on my model changes like it is in entity framework by default. (I have already tried sequelize-mig and sequelize-auto-migration npm packages, but they didn't work)
2. Is it possible to let a sequelize model inheritate from an other sequelize model. For instance I have a model User which has the properties name and password (only an example). Now I want to expand the model by creating a new model that should have the name UserWithToken and should extend User and has an additional attribute token. Is this possible?